# Grunt executes multiple times, creates infinite loop

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

We are working as on a project with a couple of other devs on GIT, using the same repo, it works fine with everyone else. However, when I run grunt it executes multiple times, seems to be running into an infinite loop, without me actually making any changes. It's only happening to me on a different computer
I am considering that maybe I need something else installed.
I deleted node, npm and reinstalled with homebrew which I'm also using for updates. Node v5.3.0, npm  3.3.12
Running Mavericks.

What am I missing?

Here's the loop:

```
    Reloading watch config...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "Gruntfile.js" changed.
>> File "js/all-js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" changed.
>> File "js/all-js/site.js" changed.
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created.

Done, without errors.
Completed in 3.740s at Tue Jan 05 2016 13:11:07 GMT-0500 (ECT) - Waiting...
[BS] File changed: js/site.min.js

Reloading watch config...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "js/all-js/bootstrap.js" changed.
>> File "Gruntfile.js" changed.
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created.

Done, without errors.
Completed in 1.869s at Tue Jan 05 2016 13:11:10 GMT-0500 (ECT) - Waiting...
[BS] File changed: js/site.min.js
>> File "js/all-js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" changed.
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created.

Done, without errors.
Completed in 1.885s at Tue Jan 05 2016 13:12:04 GMT-0500 (ECT) - Waiting...
[BS] File changed: js/site.min.js

Reloading watch config...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "Gruntfile.js" changed.
```

Here's my Gruntfile.js:

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

//Get all tasks from the package.json file
require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),    

    /* Concurrent Task */          

    concurrent: {
        watch: {
            tasks: ['watch', 'compass:dist', 'browserSync'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        }
    },

    /* SASS task */

     compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
              sassDir: ['SASS/'],
              cssDir: ['css/'],
              environment: 'development', /* development | production */
              importPath: ['SASS/'],
              outputStyle: 'compressed', /* expanded for development | compressed for production */
              watch: true,
              sourcemap: true
            },
        },
        live: {
            options: {
              sassDir: ['SASS/'],
              cssDir: ['css/'],
              environment: 'production', /* development | production */
              importPath: ['SASS/'],
              outputStyle: 'compressed', /* expanded for development | compressed for production */
              watch: false,
              force: true,                      
            },
        },          
    },      

    /* Javascript Tasks */

    uglify: {
        // Uglify files

        build: {
            src: [
                'js/all-js/bootstrap.js',
                'js/all-js/site.js'
            ],
            dest: 'js/site.min.js'
        }

    },

    /* Run tasks when needed */

    watch: {            
        js: {
            files: ['js/all-js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify'],
            options: { livereload: true }
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js'],
            options: {reload: true}
        }
    },

    /* Browser Reload with BrowserSync */

    browserSync: {
        bsFiles: {
            src : [
                'css/**/*.css',
                'js/site.min.js',
                '**/*.php'
            ]
        },
    }       


});

// Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.

grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent:watch']);
grunt.registerTask('live', ['compass:live']);
```

};

Here's my package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "ourframework",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "~0.4.1",
      "grunt-contrib-compass": "*",
      "grunt-browser-sync": "*",
      "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
      "grunt-concurrent": "*",
      "grunt-contrib-uglify": "*",      
      "matchdep": "*"
    }
   }
```

Comment: I just tested this exact setup in a different computer and runs fine!

Comment: Please read my answer below - it will always run fine as there is no problem. The 'loop' you are seeing is simply compilations that are happening later, when something changes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the timestamps in the grunt output, eg:

```
Completed in 3.740s at Tue Jan 05 2016 13:11:10
Completed in 1.885s at Tue Jan 05 2016 13:12:04
```

Notice these compilations are a minute apart - you are running the grunt `watch` task. This will watch a set of specified files and re-run tasks if there are any changes.

There is no 'loop' - it will simply re-compile every time something changes, which is often desirable.

You can see your default task is set to `concurrent:watch`

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent:watch']);
```

So if you just type `grunt`, it will run that task.